# PHP artisan error: CLI stops working after every reboot

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

I installed Laravel through composer using PHP 7.3.25 through xampp v3.2.4. I first noticed the problem: cli stopped working, during

```
php artisan serve
```

I scoured SO and the internet for possible fixes. Going through these commands fixed this problem for me (or so I thought):

```
composer update --no-scripts
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

But every time I turn on the PC, I get the same error and have to follow these steps to make it work. Antivirus did not have anything to do with it (I checked). Is there any way to fix this without having to completely reinstall everything?

Comment: serve your website by `xampp` not `php artisan serve` and make sure your startup application container `xampp`

Comment: If you have an issue setting up a virtual host, this may help you out https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

Comment: please also post the error

Comment: Please share more details - what is "this problem"?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being vague, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Its ist important to understant few points related to following queue:restart command.
The queue workers' age confirmed that they restarting in response to that.

php artisan queue:restart

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

Comment: Please share more details. How does that single command help to avoid the problem given in the question?